# What is the best way to read Excel File using VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, excel

As far as I know there are 2-ways  to read Excel files using VB.NET which are using:

1. OLEDB
2. COM component

   I am using both but I want to know which is more efficient or best method to use when it comes to reading Excel data.

I am currently working on extracting a specific record on a spreadsheet with massive number of data, thousands of rows and still counting.

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: OLEDB. Since it doesn't require Excel to be installed and SQL can be used. My personal opinion.

Comment: Why not try both and see which is faster? I would still use oledb and SQL

Comment: @YuriyGalanter, When I deploy/pack my project, I include the components needed so it wouldn't require to install Excel or Microsoft Office.

Comment: @Jeff, I don't know how and what to test the speed.

Comment: Use the stopwatch class to time how long each way takes.

Comment: In the first instance, I use a stopwatch (on my phone) to do speed tests. Or you could edit you code to record start/end times.